# Transformation of scentences

Tags: grammar

I want to know answer of this question:- "Do you like something?" the friend asked.(remove inverted commas)

Comment: Are you puzzled about how to refer to the askee?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, could you [edit] to make it clearer please.

Comment: By "inverted commas" do you mean quotation marks?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the person who asked this wants to know if you liked something that you were looking at. So, if you did like something, then you would say yes, if not, you would say no. Also, a little tip that might help you out later, the " are called quotation marks. They're used when quoting another person, or in stories to show that someone is talking.